# How to pass objects from one controller to another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On an unsuccessful save, I would like to redirect to the previous view but with the error message.

```
redirect_to user_path(@user_id), errors: @user.errors
```

but in the view, when I check for `errors` I get an undefined variable errors.

I am not using the same controller new and create, so I can't have @user.errors.any in new.html.erb. I have two different controllers, one in which form is there, and another controller which will take care of create, if the create is not happening I need to redirect to the previous controller.

Comment: You have to set flash[:error] to your expected error message, then you should be able to access it in the views using the same flash[:error].

Comment: I don't want to use flash here @Mohanraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the parameters inside the redirect_to helper like below,

```
redirect_to user_path(id: @user_id, error: @user.errors.messages)
```

Please check the rake routes and pass the appropriate **key for id**, whether it's **:id, or :user_id**

Comment: params[:error]
=> "#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f4ab4014b80>"
Okay, Now I am able to get the error in params, but it's coming like this. How do I parse this object?

Comment: Yeh I think, i will prefer user.errors.messages .. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use [render](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) instead of `redirect_to`.
Something like this:

```
# controller_1
def step_1
  @user = User.new
  @user.do_something
  ...
end

# controller_2
def step_2
 if @user.save?
   # redirect to another...
 else
   render 'controller_1/step_1`
 end
end
```

Then on view `step_1.html.erb`, you can print out errors of `@user` with `@user.errors`.